# Last selected date is not getting in datepicker dialog

Tags: android, android-datepicker

In my app I have one datepicker, I am able to select and set the selected date in textview, but the issue is if again I click on textview to open datepicker dialog, it always shows current date instead of last selected date..so what is the issue?

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView date_dropdown;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    date_dropdown=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.shows_dt);
    
    
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    date_dropdown.setText(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "-"
            + (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-"
            + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));

    date_dropdown.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDatePickerDialog();
        }
    });
}

public void showDatePickerDialog() {

    System.out.println("show date picke dilg ");
    System.out.println("show date picke dilg");

    DialogFragment newFragment1 = new SelectDateFragment();
    newFragment1.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
}

public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
        populateSetDate(yy, mm + 1, dd);
    }

    public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        date_dropdown.setText(day + "-" + month + "-" + year);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below Line You Have Given get only Current date,
so You will Get current date only.

```
 date_dropdown.setText(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "-"
        + (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-"
        + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

save your Selected date in Shared Preference then Show in your TextView

Comment: on my second click of textview..i want previous selected date in datepicker..that is the issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30455168/4447803- use this code it works what you need

Comment: it may Help your problem ,Just Accept the answer

Answer (score 2):

You should define calender instance in `onCreate()` method and then all year month and date value update `onDateSet()`, So when you again open date picker dialog it will surly display  previously selected date.

Do just like this

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView date_dropdown;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


       final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int yy1 = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mm1 = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dd1 = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    date_dropdown=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.shows_dt);


    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    date_dropdown.setText(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "-"
            + (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-"
            + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));

    date_dropdown.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDatePickerDialog();
        }
    });
}

public void showDatePickerDialog() {

    System.out.println("show date picke dilg ");
    System.out.println("show date picke dilg");

    DialogFragment newFragment1 = new SelectDateFragment();
    newFragment1.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
}

public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy1, mm1, dd1);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
        populateSetDate(yy, mm + 1, dd);

         yy1 = yy ;
         mm1 = mm;
         dd1 = dd ;
    }

    public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        date_dropdown.setText(day + "-" + month + "-" + year);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're creating a new dialog every time you click, which means `onCreateDialog` is setting the date to the current time again. You want to have a class variable `DialogFragment df`, and in your `showDatePickerDialog` do something like this:

```
public void showDatePickerDialog() {
    if (df == null){
        // Only create a new fragment if one does not exist
        DialogFragment df = new SelectDateFragment();
    }
    df.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
}
```

You will also want to store the value the user selects in your `onPause` method and set the `DialogFragment` to that value in `onResume`, in case your user navigates away from your app while inputting information.

Comment: public void showDatePickerDialog() {

  DialogFragment df = null ;
  if (df == null){
         // Only create a new fragment if one does not exist
        df = new SelectDateFragment();
     }
     df.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");

  /*DialogFragment newFragment1 = new SelectDateFragment();
  newFragment1.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");*/
 }

Comment: i did some thing like that..but issue is still same..first i open datepicker it shows current date.then i change it to 2nd june..and close datepicker dialog..it sets 2nd june in textview..till here its fine..but again i click and open dialog it still shows current date

Comment: In the code in your comment you assign the dp to null right before the if statement. That if statement will always be true and you will always create a new df. Remove that line,  and declare your df outside the method.

Answer (score 0):

[How to disable future date picker in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229816/how-to-disable-future-date-picker-in-android/44454223#44454223)

```
 mDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());


ed_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Calendar mcurrentDate=Calendar.getInstance();
                year=mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                month=mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                day=mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                final DatePickerDialog   mDatePicker =new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday)
                    {
                              ed_date.setText(new StringBuilder().append(year).append("-").append(month+1).append("-").append(day));
                            int month_k=selectedmonth+1;

                    }
                },year, month, day);
                mDatePicker.setTitle("Please select date");
                // TODO Hide Future Date Here
                mDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());

                // TODO Hide Past Date Here
                //  mDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
                mDatePicker.show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 mDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());


ed_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Calendar mcurrentDate=Calendar.getInstance();
                year=mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                month=mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                day=mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                final DatePickerDialog   mDatePicker =new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday)
                    {
                              ed_date.setText(new StringBuilder().append(year).append("-").append(month+1).append("-").append(day));
                            int month_k=selectedmonth+1;

                    }
                },year, month, day);
                mDatePicker.setTitle("Please select date");
                // TODO Hide Future Date Here
                mDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());

                // TODO Hide Past Date Here
                //  mDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
                mDatePicker.show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

**updateDate through set previous selected date in date picker**

```
mDatePicker.updateDate(1994, 6, 12);


mDatePicker.setTitle("Please select date");
mDatePicker.updateDate(1994, 6, 12);
mDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to print selected date is:

```
picker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
    tv_date.text = "picker.headerText"
}
```

`picker` is an object of DatePicker class.