# How to disable future dates in calendarView

Tags: android, date, calendarview

I want to disable the next day but not the previous day. I have found out how to disable it for the next day, but for the previous day it was also disabled. Please help me

This is my code

```
public class Kegiatan extends AppCompatActivity {

private CalendarView calendarKegiatan;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kegiatan);

    calendarKegiatan = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarKegiatan);

    calendarKegiatan.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int day) {

            Date getdate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/M/d");
            String dateNow = dateFormat.format(getdate);
            String date = year + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + day;

            if (date.equals(dateNow)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Kegiatan.this, ListKegiatan.class);
                intent.putExtra("tanggal", date);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Kegiatan.this, "Dilarang laporan di hari selanjutnya", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    calendarKegiatan.setFocusedMonthDateColor(Color.GREEN);


}
```

}

Comment: [check this link make future date disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229816/how-to-disable-future-date-picker-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your problem is quite simple. Simply setMaxDate to the current date. You can have your code like this:

```
//Declare and initialize your calendarView object.
calendarKegiatan = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarKegiatan);


//Set the maximum date
calendarKegiatan.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());


//Listen for changes to the date and paste your original logic
calendarKegiatan.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener(){...};


//Do more awesome stuff
calendarKegiatan.setFocusedMonthDateColor(Color.GREEN);
```

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
calendarKegiatan = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarKegiatan);

calendarKegiatan.setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

This should disable all future dates.

Comment: Thank you, your answer very help me sir. I tried it and added some more code and it worked